# How to parse HTML with PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)
>   [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Hello,

What is the faster and easy HTML parser for PHP 5?

Thank you

Comment: The answer to this question is usually dont, so if you let us all know why we may be able to make suggestions.

Comment: Faster and easier than.... what?

Comment: @Toby oh really? What's a better solution.. regex? :P

Answer (score 1):

if its valid xhtml, you can do this with the SimpleXML built-in library afaik

but as people mentioned, why would you want to parse it? Are you sure you dont want to search for stuff instead?

Comment: yup, xhtml is valid xml and is parseable by an xml library.

Comment: uh? HTML parsing is a perfectly valid task. And if you mean searching with XPath, then the HTML has to be parsed before too...

Comment: i was thinking about regex searches, like scanning for links :)

Comment: @Femaref: Good luck finding valid XHTML to parse though. It has been said for years that unless you *totally* control the content (i.e., no user-supplied comments or anything like that) and are willing to be anal about XML validity, XHTML is not a practical option.